# How do I use "drush make" modules with a local module code?

Tags: drush, version-control

I got to love the workflow "drush make" gives us. I am sure there are others who would want their development code to be put into a make file with it not being ready for drupal.org, for example, deploying a new development testing instance of the site quickly with a bash script or from what I have seen in Aegir.

It seems the current workflow that may suit this would be to utilize a git repository of your development code. However, my development machine is Windows 7, and I would like to use "drush make" in a virtual box with an Ubuntu server instance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Drush make also supports file:/// protocol

```
projects[my_proj][type] = "module"
projects[my_proj][subdir] = "custom"
projects[my_proj][download][type] = "git"
projects[my_proj][download][url] = "file:///path/to/my_proj.git"
projects[my_proj][branch] = "dev"
```

Use sshfs to mount the repository inside virtualbox. Guide here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS

Answer (score 10):

You can set up local domains and local git repositories or tarballs like so:

```
projects[my_module][type] = "module"
projects[my_module][download][type] = "file"
projects[my_module][download][url] = "http://localhost/my_module.tgz"
projects[my_module][subdir] = "contrib"
```

Then in your build script you could just recreate the tgz

Comment: Nice thankyou that must be the same thing it does from the d.org modules, makes sense. I think I will workout the git way, just I am trying to do this from withing a linux vm on a windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can install [make_local](https://www.drupal.org/project/make_local), which extends `drush make` capabilities to also source modules from directory trees. Use it like this:

```
projects[my_proj][type] = "module"
projects[my_proj][subdir] = "custom"
projects[my_proj][download][type] = "local"
projects[my_proj][download][source] = "../relative/path/to/my_proj_dir"
```

**Advantages over "normal" `drush make`:** **(1)** In contrast to `file://` URLs, you can use relative paths. **(2)** You do not need to package your module into a `.tar.gz` beforehand, or to source it from a git repo directory. A normal directory is enough.

The directory with the module *could* be a git repo of course, but does not have to. (In your case, a Windows 7 host OS directory that is accessible via VirtualBox shared directories would do. No need to install `git` inside the VM.)

Answer (score 0):

in case you drush-make a distro from a gitweb site via build makefile take care to quote the url as it contains semicolons, my question about that was here on [drush make on local gitweb raw url](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/81021/drush-make-on-local-gitweb-raw-url)

Comment: Thanks! (I think this would be better as a comment to one of the answers from above though.)