# drush make on local gitweb raw url

Tags: version-control, drush

I moved a git repo from github to local gitweb and want to access the raw build make file

http://git.mycompany.com/?p=workflow.git;a=blob_plain;f=build-workflow.make;h=170f5329b413bea0efb1ec33bebdc1549403cc3e;hb=HEAD

opening that url in browser is fine:   raw code same as in github

But drush make complains about missing core and api entries.

So I checked with wget and it saves a `index.html?p=workflow.git' which is a complete html page.

How is that supposed to work on gitweb ??

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution : the shell is interpreting the semicolons and cuts the URL so it has to be quoted. Here for example http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/ticket/9358 it is explained.

my drush cmd should be:

```
drush make "http://git.mycompany.de/?p=workflow.git;a=blob_plain;f=build-workflow.make;h=170f5329b413bea0efb1ec33bebdc1549403cc3e;hb=HEAD"
```