# Profiler builder with custom modules

Tags: 7, drush, installation-profiles

First things first: happy 2015 to everybody. :-)

Now, I am quite new with Drupal distributions and profiles and here is my situation: I have a running site where I have contributed modules and custom modules. I've installed profiler builder module. When I use `drush distro` to create a distribution, it generates 2 make files: drupal-org.make and local.make.example. The last one "contains" the first one and it contains the custom modules as well.

When I run `drush make local.make.example ./destfolder`, it throws some errors. It says "non-existent project type on custom-module". So after a bit of research I've been able to make it work adding some information to the local.make.example, and adding the custom modules in a zip format.

My question is, why does drush distro generates a useless folder structure (i.e. modules, themes, libraries)? Am I able to put something there to make drush-make work on local.make.example without needing to add extra information? Am I missing something?

The extra lines of code I added in each custom module to the local.make.example was:

- projects[custom_module_name][type] = "module"
- projects[custom_module_name][download][type] = "file"
- projects[custom_module_name][download][url] = localurl

Thanks very much for your time and let me know if you need further information.

**EDIT**

I'm going a bit crazy about this… I've just found out that drush make creates the custom modules' folders but they are empty. Nothing inside… So basically, I just don't know how to tell drush-make to build the initial drupal folder's architecture when custom modules are stored on the same computer I'm executing drupal-make…

I've seen most of the examples that evolves custom modules use git, but I'd just like to know how to make it work with custom modules stored on my machine, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, Profiler Builder has problem with modules, that are not full projects on drupal.org. I tried to use a module, that is hosted in GIT repository and the output was similar to yours. But it worked fine with `drush generate-makefile`, where generated output was like:

`projects[svg][type] = "module"
projects[svg][download][type] = "git"
projects[svg][download][url] = "http://git.drupal.org/sandbox/josegaert/1511596.git"
projects[svg][download][branch] = "7.x-1.x-dev"
projects[svg][download][revision] = "04db94c4dc2bf5c8c9a2a0da5452c4a79d26d863"`

I created an issue for Profiler Builder describing this at https://www.drupal.org/node/2479185. You may also want to look at https://www.drupal.org/project/make_local

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.drush.org/en/stable/make/#project-download-options you should be able to specify `url` for `file` download method. Quoting Drush help:

> The URL can also be a path to a local file either using the bare path or the file:// protocol. The path may be absolute or relative to the makefile.

There's other question similar to yours, where you can find further examples and discussion: [How do I use "drush make" modules with a local module code?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18664/how-do-i-use-drush-make-modules-with-a-local-module-code)