# Module and theme in one directory?

Tags: 7

For my project, I have a custom module, a features module and a custom theme. I want to keep all in a single Git-Repository.

The problem is: modules need to be in `sites/all/modules`, themes in `sites/all/themes`.

I know, I could bundle both in a profile. But I am already using a special profile. And as far as I know, there is no way to inherit a profile.

And yes, I know I could use symlinks. But they tend to create issues with path structures.

So is there another, maybe a "Drupal" way to bundle modules and themes in one directory?

Comment: symlinks should not create issues with path structures

Comment: How about using Drush Make? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18664/how-do-i-use-drush-make-modules-with-a-local-module-code

Comment: Why you don't store whole `sites` in your repository?

Comment: @kenorb: Well, it's a bit dirty, since you end up having foreign code (incl. changes) in your own repo. But yeah, deployment is easier that way.

Comment: I think you should keep custom module, feature module and custom theme in separate repositories and then use [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) to place them together in a single git repository, but I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the suggestion of @kenorb, I have found a good way to solve this:

I init the git repository in `drupal/`, and I put  only the following line into `.gitignore`:

```
*
```

Then, I add (by force) my custom module and theme folders:

```
$ git add -f sites/all/modules/custom
$ git add -f sites/all/themes/custom
```

With this, my repo still contains only my code and no Drupal modules. And this allows me even to track also my `.htaccess`, with:

```
$ git add -f .htaccess
```